# PHP: html table layout with data coming from query

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to fix the layout of the data coming from the database in this way:

The query is returning   names of games and the points awarded for each game.

The layout I need is like that:

in one row the name of the game and in a row below its points, two columns with this and then carriage break until all results are displayed.

Please see this image, it'll show some light:

http://217.116.9.130/wordpress/HTMLtableFROMquery.gif

What I have done by far is the following code, but I cannot display the layout needed.

```
![<?php
 echo "<table border=1><tr>";

        $count=0;
            $sql2 = "select * from games";
                $res2= $db_class->select($sql2);   
                   if (mysql_num_rows($res2)>0) {
                   while($row2 = $db_class->get_row($res2)){

                      $gname = $row2['gamename'];
                      $gpoints = $row2['gamepoints'];

                       $count++;   

                       echo"<td>".$gname."</td>";
                       if($count % 2 != 0)
                       {
                        echo "</tr><tr>";
                         echo"<td>".$gpoints."</td>";
                       }
               } 
          } 

echo "</tr></table>";  
?>
```

Comment: It's really hard. A solution might be to check if the row number is odd, so add a <tr>, while if its even just add <td>. I struggled for something like this and ended up the easier way: enclose each Result row into a <div> with float:left, so that every 2 divs the container compels the following to go under the first...You'll achieve the same result and it's easier and cleaner (imho)

Comment: I don't think it'll work. If the row number is even and he adds a `<td>`, he then goes to the next row fetched and loses the score for the first record, which should be displayed under the first record's name.

Comment: @linkyndy you're right, I thought more about it later an saw it was not right, couldn't correct my comment on time though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about some `div`s?

```
<?php
 echo "<table border=1><tr>";

        $count=0;
            $sql2 = "select * from games";
                $res2= $db_class->select($sql2);   
                   if (mysql_num_rows($res2)>0) {
                   while($row2 = $db_class->get_row($res2)){

                      $gname = $row2['gamename'];
                      $gpoints = $row2['gamepoints'];

                       $count++;   

                       echo"<td>
                        <div class=\"gname\">".$gname."</div>
                        <div class=\"gpoints\">".$gpoints."</div>
                        </td>";
                       if($count % 2 != 0)
                       {
                        echo "</tr><tr>";
                       }
               } 
          } 

echo "</tr></table>";  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a table for each set of name-score, and then style it after your needs.
You can use the `border` property in CSS to style your table, and also `table:nth-child(2n){ clear: left;` to have only two tables on each row.
I believe this method is more flexible, as CSS gives endless possibilities for styling an element.